# How to create array of array by grouping ids

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

`let array = [{id: 1, name:'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 1, name:'c'}];`

I want an array like

`arr2 = [[{id: 1, name:'a'}, {id: 1, name:'c'}], [{id: 2, name: 'b'}]]`

I tried this but I cant find which array to add to:

```
 $scope.journalsArray = response.data.body.Data;
      $scope.newArray = [];
      let idsArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < $scope.journalsArray.length; i++) {
         if(idsArray.indexOf($scope.journalsArray[i].journal_id) != -1){
          $scope.newArray.push($scope.journalsArray[i]);
         }else{
           $scope.idsArray.push($scope.journalsArray[i].journal_id);
         }
      }
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Array.reduce` over your original array.
- If a group exists that has an item with the same id, push into it.
- Otherwise create the group.

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name:'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 1, name:'c'}]
let result = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const group = acc.find(group => group.find(inner => inner.id === item.id))
  
  if (group) 
   group.push(item)
  else
   acc.push([item])
   
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **reduce(), find() and filter()** methods we can achieve this

```
let array = [
    {id: 1, name:'a'},
    {id: 2, name: 'b'},
    {id: 1, name:'c'}
];

const results = arr => {
    return arr.reduce((result, item ) => {
        if (!result.find(obj => obj[0].id === item.id)) {
            result.push(array.filter(val => val.id == item.id))   
        }
        return result;
    }, [])
}
console.log(results(array));

// ​​​​​[ [ { id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 1, name: 'c' } ], [ { id: 2, name: 'b' } ] ]​​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect the objects in the same group. Then get the values of each group as result.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name:'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' },{ id: 1, name:'c' }],
    result = Array.from(
        array
            .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, [...(m.get(o.id) || []), o]), new Map)
            .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array#reduce, Map, destructuring and Array#concat.

```js
const data = [{id: 1, name:'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 1, name:'c'}];

const res = data.reduce((a,{id,name})=>{
  return a.set(id, [{id,name}].concat(a.get(id)||[]));
}, new Map()).values();

console.log([...res]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name:'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 1, name:'c'}]
let result = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const group = acc.find(group => group.find(inner => inner.id === item.id))
  
  if (group) 
   group.push(item)
  else
   acc.push([item])
   
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name:'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 1, name:'c'}]
let result = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const group = acc.find(group => group.find(inner => inner.id === item.id))
  
  if (group) 
   group.push(item)
  else
   acc.push([item])
   
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```